# Closing Contextual add-in Card Explicitly

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

From the documentation about Contextual add-in, In order to close a card opened from a Contextual add-in, the user needs to click anywhere outside the card.

Is there any way this can be done explicitly by providing a close [X] button anywhere in the opened Card ?

Have tried to verify if there is any event triggered when closing the Card,but couldn't find any. Is there any related event for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported for add-ins today. There is no event that is triggered on add-in close / kill.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.